# pod2man fails with 'No name given for document'

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have a pod2man task which has started failing with a recent update ( now running perl 5.24.0 ). The error output is

```
[    8s] pod2man < gits-checkup > gits-checkup.1
[    9s] IO::File=IO(0x1365550) around line 1: No name given for document
[    9s] IO::File=IO(0xe06550) around line 1: No name given for document
[    9s] POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 70.
```

The complete file is hosted at [gits-checkup](https://sourceforge.net/p/gitslave/code/ci/master/tree/contrib/gits-checkup). Not sure which exact snippet to post.

How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed by adding the `--name` argument to the command invocation, e.g.

```
pod2man --name GITS-CHECKUP < gits-checkup > gits-checkup.1
```